# Windows update keeps doing the same updates

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, windows-update

I have searched relentlessly for a solution to my problem, but to no good end.

I have a server which is having problems (almost) every night and the IT guy does not seem to be able to determine why (he is completely overwhelmed with other stuff too).

I found that the server has 3 updates that windows update wants to have installed, however these have been allied numerous times, and the updater keeps finding them over again.

My suspicion is that this is related to my server unresponsive problem, however even if it is not, I think that I should try to fix it anyway.

The updates are:

```
Microsoft Windows Server 2003

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2633880)
Download size: 0 KB , 0 minutes  (Downloaded; ready to install)  
A security issue has been identified that could allow an unauthenticated remote attacker to compromise your system and gain control over it. You can help protect your system by installing this update from Microsoft. After you install this update, you may have to restart your system.  Details... 
Don't show this update again 

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2572073)
Download size: 0 KB , 0 minutes  (Downloaded; ready to install)  
A security issue has been identified that could allow an unauthenticated remote attacker to compromise your system and gain control over it. You can help protect your system by installing this update from Microsoft. After you install this update, you may have to restart your system.  Details... 
Don't show this update again 

Security Update for .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2518864)
Download size: 0 KB , 0 minutes  (Downloaded; ready to install)  
A security issue has been identified that could allow an attacker to compromise your Windows-based system that is running the Microsoft .NET Framework and gain complete control over it. You can help protect your computer by installing this update from Microsoft. After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.  Details... 
Don't show this update again
```

The Don't show this update again boxes are grayed out, so I cannot ignore the updates.

I think the machine has all the frameworks installed, from 1.1 to 4.
The primary task of the server is for SQL Server 2000, although we have trial of SQL Server 2008 installed, and we plan to upgrade to windows 2008 and sql server 2012 in the future, however I really need to get this fixed.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Well is the update applied?  Read the KB associated with the updates in question.  It should tell you details about the files being updated.

Comment: Extended support for SQL Server 2000 ends April 9, 2013. Please make sure that "in the future" is a specific date that gives you plenty of time to retire SQL Server 2000 before it is abandoned.

Comment: The updates were applied, as per details in the windows update web page.

Comment: I managed to find something from Microsoft called Microsoft Fix it Center, it was able to "repair" the windows update tool, and now it has stopped asking to install these updates... I will have to see if that was actually the cause of the server freezes though.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug on Microsoft's end. People are experiencing the same problem world wide, with the same patches. KB2518864 was originally released nearly a year ago and has since been superseded by another fix. The other two were originally released earlier this year.

I've seen some people claim that uninstalling all of the .NET frameworks completely and then reinstalling them has fixed the problem but that seems a bit extreme for what is only a minor annoyance at worst. Personally, I'm going to give it a day or so to see if Microsoft figures out the problem.

Comment: I think I just found another computer with the exact same 3 updates wanted... also windows server 2003. It will only be a minor annoyance though if it is just the updates, if it is the thing freezing the server, that is quite a headache (for me at least).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to diagnose:

1. Download each update separately using the link from the MSKB article.
2. Try to install it.
3. You probably will see an interesting error message that haven't seen before.

You may need to uninstall .NET Framework 2.0, reboot, reinstall it, reboot, then run Windows Update again.

Comment: I already did try installing them separately, but it had no affect.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall .NET Framework 2.0 and report back.

Comment: The microsoft fixit tool seems to have fixed the update problem. It stopped asking for the update after I found that and executed.

Comment: @marts Congratulations! I would suggest posting a more detailed version of your comment about the "microsoft fixit tool" -- including information on what it does and where to find it -- as an answer to your own question, so that others will be able to see (and potentially upvote) your solution.

Answer (score 0):

These 3 updates downloaded and apparently installed 4 separate times on Tuesday 05-22-12.  They show up 4 times in Update History but aren't present in Add/Remove Programs.  Possibly MS took care of it by yesterday morning (05-23) because I no longer have them trying to download/install.   One interesting quirk:  yesterday morning the little yellow "update" shield was present when I turned on the computer so I started the update and immediately hit the "Cancel update" button.  Is that what stopped it?  The fixit is a popup at:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339     I haven't tried it myself, since the problem seems to have ended.  Also, I see in Update History that one of them (KB2633880) was donwloaded on 02-15-12 and also is not shown in add/remove programs.  Go figure.